# Route53 not routing traffic to Cloudfront distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

So I have a working Cloudfront distribution, but I haven't been able to use my domain name with it. I've follow tutorials, troubleshooting steps and other similar questions, but I haven't found my issue yet. This is what I've done so far:

1. Register domain name with Route 53
2. Created S3 bucket with name `www.example.com` and `example.com` redirecting to first bucket
3. Tested that my CloudFront distribution domain name works as expected
   Added alternate domain name with my domain name. I added both `example.com` and with www `www.example.com`
4. Origin domain is the S3 bucket. I left the name the same. Origin access is set to "Legacy access identities" and the identity is default "Access S3 bucket content only though CloudFront"
5. Requested and got a public ACM certificate with location us-east1 (N. Virginia). I added domain name `example.com` and a second one `*.example.com`. Certificate shows as "issued"
6. I should have created the records automatically while my certificate was loading, but I didn't. I tried creating it from ACM, but it wouldn't let me anymore. I copied the CNAME and added the record manually to Route 53. I found the hosted zone with my domain name, and copied the hash and value to create the record. Record is `_longhash.example.com` and the CNAME value from ACM.
7. CloudFront distribution has SSL certificate from previous step selected. I double check is `example.com`. It also has IPV6 enabled
8. I created an A record with `www.example.com` mapping to my distribution (I do find my distribution in the dropdown, and I checked that the Id matches)
9. I created an AAAA record same as step before (for IPV6)
   NS and SOA records were created automatically by Route 53 and I haven't touched them
10. I have waited for more than 2 days

When I go to the website `example.com` I just get a redirect to my ISP page. It says that the connection is not secure. So I'm guessing it's something wrong with the certificate.
What am I missing or what did I do wrong?

Comment: When I get a chance today, I'm thinking to delete and recreate the ACM certificate. Maybe something went wrong in aws end. I'm kind of clueless at this point tbh.

Comment: An issue with the SSL certificate would not cause this issue, and if there was a problem with the DNS records for SSL certificate validation, AWS ACM would have never issued you the certificate.

Comment: You say you created an `A` record for `www.example.com` but you are trying to go to `example.com` in the browser. Did you also create an `A` record for `exmaple.com`? You have to point the root domain to CloudFront if you want to be able to enter the root domain in the browser and have it served by CloudFront.

Comment: I didn't, but I just added two more records an A and AAAA record for `example.com`. And what do you mean when saying "point domain to CloudFront"? I have two alternate domain names to `example.com` and `www.example.com`. Am I missing something there with CloudFront?

Comment: ultimately I'd like both `example.com` and `www.example.com` to route to my website.

Comment: The A record points the domain to CloudFront. That's what a DNS record does, it points a domain name to something. The "value" of the record is what the domain name points to. The domain `example.com` and the subdomain `www.example.com` are not the same thing. You have to setup both of them if you want both of them to work. It sounds like you didn't setup the DNS for the root domain until just now. Does it work now?

Comment: It's still not working. It just shows now "This site can't be reached"

Comment: Did you actually point the A record for the root domain to CloudFront? Without any more details there isn't much more anyone can help you with here.

Comment: I am checking the info in the records again. I have 4 Alias records (2 A and 2 AAAA). Record name are `example.com` and `www.example.com` value of all of them is the CloudFront distribution url. If I copy the value to the browser, it opens the website correctly. Alias is set to true in all of them and they have Simple routing policy. TTL is undefined.

Comment: I would go here and put the domain name in, and verify it is actually resolving to the correct value now https://dnschecker.org/

Comment: It just shows "Not resolved"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257103/discussion-between-felipe-centeno-and-mark-b).

Comment: It seems it is working now.

Comment: Well after a long search I was able to find my issue. When I registered my domain name, a hosted zone was created which gave me the impression that they were connected. However, the server names were not matching and I just needed to update my domain server names to match those in the hosted zone.